# Console App how to run a function by entering action into cmd

Tags: c#, asp.net, command, console-application

In a C# console application in VS 2010 I have...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to c#");

        Console.WriteLine(DownloadPOS());
```

when I hit play this opens the command prompt, displays 'Welcome to c#' and runs the function 'DownloadPOS'.

I would like to remove the `Console.WriteLine(DownloadPOS());`, run the program and have to manually enter the text 'DownloadPOS()' into the the command line. How can I do this? I've tried opening a cmd and navigating to the project.?

I've also tried right clicking on the project/properties/debug and entering DownloadPOS() into the command line argument and running the project in debug. Should this run the function?

Comment: you need get user input if they enter a string as DownloadPOS() then execute function.

Comment: what? sorry im confused. I run the app. then what?

Comment: unless you are trying to get something more, you can just do `if(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "DOWNLOADPOS") { DownloadPOS(); }

Comment: see @Jonesy answer he gave you an example

Comment: where do i enter that in the Main, or in the command line arguments in debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to c#");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if(input.ToUpper() == "DOWNLOADPOS")
       DownloadPOS();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. why is the string 'DOWNLOADPOS' in uppercase? Also nothing happens when I runs this, console app just remains in loading screen with flashing cursor, instead of jumping do to the 'DownloadPOS' function which i have breakpointed

Comment: step through the code, read what happens during Console.ReadLine()

Comment: Apologies but I am stepping through it, command window shows 'Welcome to c#' and when i try to f11 on string.input = console.readline it steps on but I can see where, and the play button is disabled?

Comment: it's waiting for user input.  Console.ReadLine() waits for the user to type and press return in the console

Answer (score 2):

You would like to do something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to c#");
    Console.WriteLine("Please select an option.\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Select D for DownLoadPos(), U for UpLoadPos() ...\n");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    switch(input)
    {
          case "D": 
          { 
               DownloadPOS();
               break;
          }
          case "U": 
          { 
               //UpLoadPOS(); // This is not a real method. Just for explanation
               break;
          }
          default:
          {
               Console.WriteLine("You have not selected an option.\n");
               Console.WriteLine("The program will now exit. \n");                   
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
               break;
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("Welcome to c#");

    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    if(input.ToUpper() == "DOWNLOADPOS")
       DownloadPOS();
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to c#");

        // Example 1
        if (args.Count() > 0 && args[0].ToUpper().Equals("DOWNLOADPOS1"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called via Arguments");
            DownloadPOS();
        }
        // Example 2
        else if ("DOWNLOADPOS2" == Console.ReadLine().ToUpper())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called via user input");
            DownloadPOS();
        }

        // To stop command prompt disappearing
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DownloadPOS()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello from DownloadPOS");
    }
}
```

If you put DOWNLOADPOS1 as the argument, program will call your method. Output would be;

Welcome to c#
Called via Arguments
Hello from DownloadPOS

If you remove command line arguments and then run the program, then it will wait for your input. Type "DOWNLOADPOS2" and it'll execute your method. Command prompt will be like;

Welcome to c#
DOWNLOADPOS2
Called via user input
Hello from DownloadPOS